# How to wait for async component mounted in vue 3?

Tags: async-await, vuejs3, async-components

```
<template>
    <HelloWorld v-if="isShow" ref="comp"></HelloWorld>
    <button @click="show">Show</button>
</template>
<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent, ref, nextTick } from 'vue'
export default {
    components: {
        HelloWorld: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./HelloWorld.vue))
    },
    setup() {
        const isShow = ref(false)
        const comp = ref(null)
        const show = async () => {
            isShow.value = true
            await nextTick()
            console.log(comp.value) // return null
            
            // this works
            setTimeout(() => {console.log(comp.value)}, 300)

        }
        return {isShow, comp, show}
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to access HelloWorld component after mounted but console log show that comp.value is null.

It works when I use setTimeout for 300ms instead of nextTick but I don't want to use that approach.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I see it if you want to avoid using `setTimeout`. First I apologize in advance, my solution is in `Composition API` I'm more comfortable with this syntax. I hope it will help you still.

You need to create an `emit` that will be trigger when the component is mounted. This way, when the `emit` is trigger, your `comp.value` is initialized and mounted.

`Parent.vue` :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { defineAsyncComponent, ref } from 'vue';

  const HelloWorld = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./HelloWorld.vue'));

  const isShow = ref(false);
  const comp = ref(null);
  const show = async () => {
    isShow.value = true;
  };

  const consoleComp = () => {
    console.log(comp.value);
  };
</script>

<template>
  <HelloWorld
    v-if="isShow"
    ref="comp"
    @mounted="consoleComp"
  />
  <button @click="show">Show</button>
</template>
```

`HelloWorld.vue` :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

  const greeting = ref('Hello, world!');

  const emit = defineEmits(['mounted']);

  onMounted(async () => {
    emit('mounted');
  });
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope it helps you ! :)

Comment: Thanks it works. I still don't know why nextTick() not work in thís case. Can you explain?